# Grouping rows in Jquery DataTable

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

I am using following code to group rows based on the second column (status) in a jQuery DataTable. It works but it orders the group either ascending or descending. What I want is a custom order of the groups, for example the groups should be displayed like Payed, Approved, New,...etc. not ascending or descending.

```
var table = $('#tblInvoices').dataTable({
    "columnDefs": [
        { "visible": false, "targets": 2 }
    ],
    "order": [[2, 'dsc']],
    "displayLength": 50,
    "lengthMenu": [
        [50, 100, 200, -1],
        [50, 100, 200, "All"]
    ],
    "drawCallback": function (settings) {
        var api = this.api();
        var rows = api.rows({ page: 'current' }).nodes();
        var last = null;

        api.column(2, { page: 'current' }).data().each(function (group, i) {
            if (last !== group) {
                $(rows).eq(i).before(
                    '<tr class="group"><td colspan="9">' + group + '</td></tr>'
                );

                last = group;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: What if you add an invisible column with a number, like 1 for Payed, 2 for Approved and so on... and group by it?

Comment: invisible column you mean a td with display = none?

Comment: Yes, something like that. It is just a suggestion as i have not dealt with jquery datatable before. Also, if you are able to customize your data, i think you could make your data to be as `1 - Payed`, `2 - Approved`.

Comment: it does not work for me in this case because I show the status as a  extra row over all other rows with same status